# MacBook Pro not filling the entire screen of external display

Tags: macbook-pro, display

[image: Display left side border is unused]

I recently bought an LG 22MP68VQ, but when I connect it
MacBook Pro (13 inch, 2016) + Big Sur OS + USB Connector + VGA Cable.

But it's working fine when I am connecting an HP + Windows + VGA cable.
Any solution

Comment: I really wouldn't use a VGA cable. I suspect your problem is somewhere there. Use an HDMI cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because the graphics card adjusts the resolution on both devices. If you want everything to be filled on your external monitor, you have to specify it in the Macbook settings under Monitors. (If you used sync screens).

Regardless of that, VGA cables would no longer be used in this age. There are many advantages to using an HDMI / Display Port. Try it out.

Comment: It's working fine after HDMI